# Parsing string to datetime

Tags: c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

I'm writing a application on managed c++ so my problem is I can't seem to find fast and easy way to parse this string to DateTime:

```
2011-11-21 18:24:58
```

Comment: Have you tried DateTime Parse method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) ?

Comment: are you really using managed extension for c++? That's _old_. Have provisionally added the [tag:c++-cli] tag

Comment: i know it is old... but the program i`m working on was created 10 years ago... so there was no C# back then :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
using namespace System;
DateTime^ dt = gcnew DateTime;
dt = DateTime::Parse("2011-11-21 18:24:58");
```

If Parse is unable to parse your string into a date time, it will throw an FormatException, which you can catch and examine the error to see why it failed.

```
try
{
    using namespace System;
    DateTime^ dt = gcnew DateTime;
    dt = DateTime::Parse("2011-11-21 18:24:58");
}
catch (FormatException^ e)
{
    System::Console::WriteLine(e->Message);
}
```

Comment: I fixed your exception handling. Correct me if I'm wrong (I don't imagine this was valid for the old 'managed extensions' CLR support too)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help mate!

Comment: Thanks sehe, I think you are correct, you have to catch managed C++ exceptions as managed references, so your corrections are correct. :)

Comment: Wouldn't `DateTime^ dt  = DateTime::Parse("2011-11-21 18:24:58");` do it?

Comment: @Maxim Yes, probably. Been a while since I used c++/cli.

Comment: `DateTime` is a value type, not a reference type, so using `^` here is erroneous.

Comment: @ildjarn: Wrong and silly perhaps, but not erroneous.  Handles to value types are legal.  Creating a new instance of `DateTime` only to overwrite it with the return value is also wrong.

Comment: @Ben : `dt = DateTime::Parse("2011-11-21 18:24:58");` yields a compiler error, because `Parse` does not return a handle.

Comment: @ildjarn: I use boxing so little, I don't remember the syntax.  But I think it would be `dt = %DateTime.Parse(s);`

Comment: @Ben : I think it would be `*dt = DateTime.Parse(s);`, but that's beside the point -- my point is simply that the code (as-is) _is_ erroneous, as it yields a compiler error.